# Using django CSRF middleware with views returning JsonResponse

Tags: django, api, request, response, csrf

I want to use CSRF middleware with API Views in Django. Here is a demo view I want to use CSRF with, I am confused how to integrate CSRF here.

```
def login(request):
    try:
        if len(DemoTable.objects.filter(phone=int(request.POST['user'])).filter(password=sha1Engine(request.POST['password'])))==1:
            print(DemoTable.objects.filter(phone=int(request.POST['user'])).filter(password=sha1Engine(request.POST['password'])))
            return JsonResponse({'exit':'0','msg':'Success'})
        return JsonResponse({'exit':'2','msg':'User Invalid'})
    except Exception as e:
        return JsonResponse({'exit':'10','msg':'Unknown Error Occured'})
```

Any  help or suggestions will be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can get the token with `django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)`

And then set it in the header of the requests made client-side https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/csrf/#setting-the-token-on-the-ajax-request

Answer (score 3):

To set the cookie in the response, use the [`@ensure_csrf_cookie`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/csrf/#django.views.decorators.csrf.ensure_csrf_cookie) decorator:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie

@require_http_methods(["GET"])
@ensure_csrf_cookie
def list_things(request):
    return JsonResponse({
        "things": ["foo", "bar"],
    })
```

```sh
$ curl -i http://localhost:8000/api/v1/things
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Vary: Cookie
Set-Cookie:  csrftoken=nm4SdMB0pobkQ1ab7wZTFdwMlX8wr0vfT4iAg6Nqpcatl7ITRi9VOHrKf0Krbp2i; expires=Thu, 05 Mar 2020 15:25:53 GMT; Max-Age=31449600; Path=/; SameSite=Lax

{"things": ["foo", "bar"]}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)
```

ok then this will do what you need

Comment: I know how to integrate CSRF with forms, I am trying to add CSRF with simple JSON APIs here.

Comment: Adding @csrf_protect makes no sense, as long as you dont disable CSRF middleware every view is protected by it as default. 
What my question here is, how do I get {{csrf_token}} value to send it with JsonResponse.

Comment: @TheDeadMayan The only time this is necessary, as far as I've seen, is on a LoginView POST route. For some reason this wouldn't verify any csrf tokens, so I had to enforce it with the decorator. However, I had to create a custom csrf middleware to send out the token because the only way I could protect a login route was to set the csrf to use sessions and then use `enforce_csrf_cookie` on the home page route so I can get back the session cookie